# Parsing data from .mat file and putting them to a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, mat

I have a .mat file which contains data arranged in an excel-like structure with 4 rows and 100 columns.

What I want is to take each one of these 100 columns and put in a 2x2 matrix A(:,:,j), where j = 1:100, in an .m file so that I can then run my code that processes that data.

How can I do that?

EDIT: When I use at the command window

```
load C:\...\file.mat
```

I get in the workspace window the name of the variable (let's say, fileVariable) and its value is <4x100 complex double>.

When I use in an .m file

```
S = load('C:\...\file.mat');
S
```

and run the script, at the workspace window I get the name of the variable (S) and that this variable  S has a type  <1x1 struct>.

In both cases, this is not what I want - I can't manipulate in an .m file any of this things (in contrast with a matrix, for example).

I haven't use a .mat file before, this is new for me. I just got this .mat file for this project as an input from a colleague and I have to work with it.

Comment: You've basically written the answer in your question. SO is not a code writing service, what have you tried and what is the issue?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Let me rephrase my question. When I load this .mat file at the command window of Matlab, I get a 4x100 complex double variable. In an .m file, I cannot assign this variable to a 4x100 array. When I use A = load('file.mat'), what I get is not a 4x100 array [A1 A2 ... A100].

Comment: That is not even remotely the same question. Please *edit* your question with examples that allow us to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Please read again my original question. It says exactly the same thing as in my previous comment. I want to take these 100 columns from the .mat file and put them in a 2x2 matrix A(:,:,j). But for start, let's just say, to make it easier, that I wanted to put this 4x100 variable in a 4x100 array A. What I want to emphasize is that my problem is not so much the algorithm to convert an 4x100 array to a 2x2 matrix. My problem is that the .mat file gives me some kind of "struct" or whatever that is, and this is not manipulable in an .m file as an array or matrix.

Comment: lol. Your original question says you have a `4x100` array and makes no mention of a structure. Your first comment says you don't get a `4x100` array and still makes no mention of a structure. I guess that says the same thing, even though it doesn't at all. Not until your second comment do you mention details relevant to your actual question: your data is loaded as a structure. Maybe these important details would be good to include with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are calling [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) with an output variable, the described behavior is well defined in the documentation:

> `S = load(___)` loads data into `S`, using any of the input arguments in
>   the previous syntax group.
>
> If `filename` is a MAT-file, then `S` is a structure array.
>
> If `filename` is an ASCII file, then `S` is a double-precision array containing data from the file.

Since you are loading a `*.mat` file, you get a [`structure` array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html). [You access data in a structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-structure-array.html) using the dot notation along with any valid MATLAB indexing syntax.

Since you've provided nothing to reproduce your issue, here's an example from the documentation:

```
S = load('clown.mat')
upperLeft = S.X(1:50,1:80);
image(upperLeft);
```

Which plots a subset of the full image.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that! This actually gives me a 4x100 matrix! Now I have just to separate it to 100 (2x2) matrices, but that's another problem and probably needs another question.....

Comment: Yes, it would be a separate question. Give [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) a try before you ask.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thanks again!